# Asp.Net returns empty JSON instead of Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have this code, to get the messages from database:

```
[HttpGet]
        public string RecieveMessagesFromDatabase(int ChatID)
        {
// Before - Query formatting and execution
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < UserList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (ChatID == 1)
                        {
                            TempMessageStorage.Add(
                                new Messages(reader["Message"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(reader["SenderID"]),
                                reader["Date"].ToString(), ReceiverID, groupid));
                        } // Public Chat
                        else if (ChatID == 2)
                        {
                            if (i == Convert.ToInt32(reader["SenderID"]) || i == Convert.ToInt32(reader["ReveiverID"]))
                            {
                                TempMessageStorage.Add(
                                new Messages(reader["Message"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(reader["SenderID"]),
                                reader["Date"].ToString(), ReceiverID, groupid));
                            }
                        } // Private Chat
                        else if(ChatID == 3)
                        {
                            if (i == Convert.ToInt32(reader["SenderID"]) || i == Convert.ToInt32(reader["ReveiverID"]))
                            {
                                TempMessageStorage.Add(
                                new Messages(reader["Message"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(reader["SenderID"]),
                                reader["Date"].ToString(), ReceiverID, groupid));
                            }
                        } // Group Chat
                    }
                }
                return JsonSerializer.Serialize(TempMessageStorage);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Content(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
                _Connection.Connection.Close();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

In `TempMessageStorage` Messages are present, and it is not empty. But JSON returns the empty result. But not really empty. It seems to get the number of records, but they are empty. That's how it looks like - https://prnt.sc/u3d8gc

Messages class contains

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding get and set to your properties on the model class.

Comment: Do you even need to serialise? just return the `TempMessageStorage` and change the return type to `List<TempMessgeStorage>` should be enough.

Comment: Well... And how client with JS will be using data without JSON formatting?

Comment: @Raitis the data will be formatted by ASP.NET itself, based on the request's `Accept-Type` header. Have you noticed that **no ASP.NET tutorial or sample** serializes explicitly?

Comment: In C# properties aren't just getter and setter methods, they are part of the class's interface. Fields are *not*, even if they are public. They're just implementation details. Serializers by default work with properties, not fields. Your DTO has no properties, so nothing will be serialized. While you can configure the serializer to work with fields, the proper solution is to use properties

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain that in C# ASP.NET APIs you don't need to serializer/deserialize object because they will be returned as a json by default, image

```
[HttpGet]
public object Get()
{
    return new { number = 1, word = "hi" };
}
```

In the client side they would get a json describing that object, you don't need to serialize. The json would be like this:

```
{"number":1,"word":"hi"}
```